# Button Click is not working after WebMethod function

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

On my web page I used jquery and ajax to call a C# function to fill Dropdown list with respect to another [image]
Dropdown Branch is filled as per the selection of zone and Employee with the selection of branch.It works perfect But the button Click is not working after this.Someone please tell me why this button click is not working??

[Button click works when no drop down selection is made]

my Code look Like this:

**Jquery**

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


    $(function () {

        $('#<%= ddZone.ClientID %>').change(function () {  
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Reports.aspx/BranchFill",
                data: "{'Zone':'" + $("[id*=ddZone] option:selected").text() + "'}",
                     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                     dataType: "json",
                     success: OnSuccess,
                     failure: function (response) {
                         alert(response.d);
                     }

           });
            function OnSuccess(response) {

                var ddlBranch = $("[id*=ddBranch]");
                ddlBranch.empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0">--Select--</option>');
                $.each(response.d, function () {
                    ddlBranch.append($("<option></option>").val(this['Value']).html(this['Text']));
                });

                if (response.d == "false") {
                         alert("Not found");                           
                     }
                 }

        });


    $('#<%= ddBranch.ClientID %>').change(function () {  
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Reports.aspx/EmployeeFill",
            data: "{'Branch':'" + $(this).val() + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }

        });
        function OnSuccess(response) {

            var ddlEmployee = $("[id*=ddEmployee]");
            ddlEmployee.empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0">--Select--</option>');
            $.each(response.d, function () {
                ddlEmployee.append($("<option></option>").val(this['Value']).html(this['Text']));
            });

            if (response.d == "false") {
                alert("Not found");                           
            }
        }

    });

   });


</script>
```

**C#**

```
 [System.Web.Services.WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public static Object BranchFill(string Zone)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        var obj = new Reports();
        List<ListItem> Branch = new List<ListItem>();

        DataTable dt = obj.CS.StaticZoneBranch(Zone, "", "SelectBranch");

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                Branch.Add(new ListItem
                {
                Text  = dt.Rows[i]["Name"].ToString(),
                Value  = dt.Rows[i]["Code"].ToString()
                });                                   
            }
            return Branch;
        }
        else
        {
            return "false";
        }

    }

    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public static Object EmployeeFill(string Branch)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        var obj = new Reports();
        List<ListItem> Employee = new List<ListItem>();

        DataTable dt = obj.CS.StaticZoneBranch("", Branch, "SelectEmployee");

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                Employee.Add(new ListItem
                {
                    Text = dt.Rows[i]["Name"].ToString(),
                    Value = dt.Rows[i]["Employee Id"].ToString()
                });
            }
            return Employee;
        }
        else
        {
            return "false";
        }
    }
```

And the **button Click**(which is not working)

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReportClass RC = new ReportClass();
        if (ddZone.SelectedValue !="0")
        {
            RC.Zone = ddZone.SelectedValue;
            RC.Branch = ddBranch.SelectedValue;
            RC.EmployeeId = ddEmployee.SelectedValue;
            Report = RC.GetReport();
        }
    }
```

Why this click function is not Working, please help me to know..

Comment: @YvetteColomb I placed a break point on the button click , break point works on button click when no selection is made..!! and after selection its not working

Comment: "not working" is not an error message or problem description. Have you checked for javascript errors in your browser console? You have two identically named OnSuccess functions, which is not a recipe for reliable code. Try naming them differently or making them anonymous

Comment: @ADyson button click causing a server error after the selecting drop down. !! i tryed renaming the function still the save result

Comment: what is the exact error? again, just saying "i get an error" does not allow anyone to help you. We need _specific, detailed_ information. You should be able to inspect the exception that is throw and get the proper details.